# WordPress: How to output Post images by category?

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, categories, posts

I'm trying to loop through all categories one by one, and printing out the post title/image/image-link. How can I make my code work?

```
<?php $categories= get_categories();
        foreach ($categories as $cat) {
            echo '<div>'.
            $posts = get_posts(array('category' => $cat->term_id));
            if ($posts) {
                foreach ($posts as $p) {
                    echo get_the_post_title( $p->title ).'<br>';
                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $p->ID, 'medium' ).'<br>';
                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail_link( $p->imagelink, 'medium' ).'<br>';
                }
            }
        }
?>
```

I know my echo statements are probably wrong in the second foreach loop, but it's absolutely important the first for loops stays the same/where it is. Please help.

Comment: You have a dot instead of a semicolon in line 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So...

1. Typo in line 3.
2. get_the_post_thumbnail() is not a function, use [get_the_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/).
3. get_the_post_thumbnail_link() is not a function (if not defined by you ofc), use [wp_get_attachment_image_src()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/).

Try this:

```
<?php $categories= get_categories();
        foreach ($categories as $cat) {
            echo '<div>';
            $posts = get_posts(array('category' => $cat->term_id));
            if ($posts) {
                foreach ($posts as $p) {
                    echo get_the_title( $p->ID ).'<br>';
                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $p->ID, 'medium' ).'<br>';
                    echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($p->ID), 'medium' )[0];

                }
            }
        }
?>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to instead of getting the original attachment image URL for the post, instead of the URL of the thumbnail? Also, will the third echo statement work if the second echo statement in the second for loop isn't there? If not, how to solve this.

Comment: Replace "medium" with "full" to get the original image.